# Media Queries not working as I progress down

Tags: css

I am curious to know how a media query of a smaller size for example 400 pixels can control elements of a desktop size screen of 1400 pixels. From my understanding of a media query is that it is only supposed to fire when at a certain screen size. Could someone help me with this issue, please.

Answer (score 0):

If your media query is set at a `@media(min-width:400px)` than it will affect all elements with a screen size GREATER than 400px since it is set at "min(imum)-width".

If you want it only to affect the elements of 400px and under screen resolution, you would use `@media(max-width:400px)`.

Per example, if you set:

```
h1 { color: red; }

@media(min-width:600px) {
  h1 { color: black; }
}

@media(min-width:900px) {
  h1 { color: white; }
}
```

Your h1 will appear red at anything UNDER 600px (since it is default), black at 600px and over, and white at 900px and over.